# Controller cannot access Child Model post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC model that instantiates 2 child models.

```
public class SModel
{
    public Pl sv = new Pl();
    public SLinks sm = new SLinks ();
}
```

When I display the data in the razor view, everything is fine:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.sv.ListOfCategories.First().Description, new { @class = "body" })
```

But when I post back to the controller, "All" the values are null or 0.

**Text Box in Razor:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.sm.YXZLink, new { @class = "post-input", @maxlength = "500" })
```

**Goes into:**

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult xxx(SModel model)

model.sm.YXZLink
```

No only this value is null or 0, but all other values are also null or 0.

Can the controller access values inside a child model?
If I am able to display child models, I should be able to access child values on the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `SModel` class contains fields only. The `DefaultModelBinder` cannot bind to fields. Instead change them to properties by adding getters and setters

```
public class SModel
{
  public Pl sv { get; set; }
  public SLinks sm { get; set }
}
```

Then initialize a new instance of each type in a parameterless constructor or assign then in the controllers GET method.

Comment: It makes sense, but I have to initialize the child models. Otherwise I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" during the Controller GET

Comment: That what the last paragraph says :)

Comment: Its a dilemma...to use the same child model for the GET and POST.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand you last comment. Whats the _dilemma_?

Comment: Doesn't it beat the purpose to create a model with child models, and then have to re-assign them again inside the controller?

Comment: And you comment about the exception your getting does not make sense. Are you trying to to pass `SModel` as a parameter in the GET method? If so don't (never ever ever do that!)

Comment: No, I am trying to populate the view with SModel. Which is working.
Like you said, since the child models are not {get; set;};, then they cannot receive values back.

Comment: You can always add a parameterless constructor in `SModel` - `public SModel() { sv = new Pl(); sm = new SLinks(); }` so they are initialized when you call `SModel model = new SModel();`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code format,

Model:

```
public class masterModel
    {
        public childModelFirst childModelFirstEntity { get; set; }
        public childModelSecond childModelSecondEntity { get; set; }
    }    
    public class childModelFirst
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
    public class childModelSecond
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("About", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="POST",InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,UpdateTargetId="target" }))
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.childModelFirstEntity.Code)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.childModelSecondEntity.Code)

        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

        var mastermdl = new masterModel();
        mastermdl.childModelFirstEntity = new childModelFirst();
        mastermdl.childModelSecondEntity = new childModelSecond();
        mastermdl.childModelFirstEntity.Code = "001";
        mastermdl.childModelSecondEntity.Code = "002";
        return View(mastermdl);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult About(masterModel model)
    {
        model.childModelFirstEntity.Code = model.childModelSecondEntity.Code;
        return View();
    }
```